# Dream Theater - Through Her Eyes (live): What does James LaBrie say before the song starts?

Tags: lyrics, live-music, prog-metal

I have been listening to **[Dream Theater](http://dreamtheater.net/) - Through Her Eyes (Live Scenes from New York)** for many years, but I was never able to understand what [James LaBrie](http://www.jameslabrie.com/) says just before the song starts.

Here below is the Spotify link to the full song:

> [Spotify](https://open.spotify.com/track/1ClfM0zUaxINcy0aLvWJqm?si=GlfvVxhoSwuakOYBEoDxWA)

And here's a short audio recording of that portion:

> [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k8nkmuiocs076o2/dream.mp3?dl=0)

What does James LaBrie say at the 0:23 minute in Spotify OR 0:17 minute in the audio recording?

Comment: Yes I thought about this. But in the YouTube version they cut what James said :(

Comment: aha yes...to me is something like: “&;:5)894 the talks and put some focus!”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Theresa Thomason, folks, on vocals!**

Comment: That makes sense because before there was the solo by the singer (Theresa) but still so hard to recognise the words! This is a breakthrough. have been listening those mysterious words since 2004 x_x

Comment: at the end of the full track he also acknowledges John Petrucci..but during the whole live he never did it for Mike Portnoy...such a shame mike eventually left the group :( mike portnoy on the drums!

Comment: Took some research, I didn't know who Theresa was until today. I have a few songs by Dream Theater, but I prefer TOOL. Maynard Keenan is hilarious and awesome. Also 2004 seems like ancient history because I was only two years old lol. Most of my music is from before my time.